My Home IP address suddenly became unreachable?
I'm running a small website on my IP (IPv4) address. Suddenly, since last night, nobody could establish a new connection to my IP, they get a connection timeout. This is despite my internet seemingly functioning normally.
I can reach all the ports internally from my LAN
Until last night, I could reach the port from the internet
I've tried a traceroute, it never reaches my IP address.
19  lag-1.hcr01bflomnar.netops.charter.com (96.34.22.167)  83.603 ms  83.720 ms  83.599 ms
20  lag-10.hcr02bflomnar.netops.charter.com (96.34.22.127)  83.422 ms  83.420 ms  83.439 ms
21  lag-18.bflomnar02h.netops.charter.com (96.34.23.19)  84.019 ms  83.880 ms  83.744 ms
(all *s below)

No matter where I traceroute from, these are always the last 3 steps (my ip is different from what's listed for lag-18), which leads me to believe that whatever node is after the lag-18 hop is what is dropping packets...
I've contacted charter, who in fact is my ISP, my account is in good standing, and after a tech was sent out, they mentioned that there's no signal issue.
So with that said, I'm out of options here. Something is dropping inbound connections, but not my outbound connections.
How can I diagnose this further?

Are you positive that your IP address simply hasn’t changed or are you paying for a static IP address?

@Ramhound I'm very sure. https://whatismyipaddress.com/ has been very consistent, even after flushing my cache.

I assume you have tried to simply reboot your system and networking equipment?

@Ramhound Yes, and the internet support has had me do the same thrice over.

Before the system became unreachable do you know you could ping it, the reason I ask, it’s not uncommon for a system not to be pingable. You will have to dive into the server logs to see when traffic stopped.

@Ramhound ICMP has always been disabled for my internet- It shouldn't have been pingable

Note that while tracert may or may not perform probes using ICMP, it does use ICMP TTL Exceeded response messages from each node along the path, so if a node doesn't respond, blocks ICMP outbound, or is filtered along the return path, the IP will not be displayed in the results. the signals may actually be reaching your IP, but the response doesn't get sent, so it appears to be unreachable. I believe Windows uses ICMP to probe, Linux uses UDP, and other systems may use TCP.

@FrankThomas so you're saying I may be getting inbound SYN, but when my server ACKs, it may be getting filtered?

well, traceroute doesn't establish a TCP (or any other kind of) connection. it just sends an IP packet with the TTL value set to X-1 where X is the hop number. the system at that hop count will then say "hey, the TTL on this packet is expired" and send that as a ICMP message back to the originating system. your router may be sending that message and its being blocked on the return path, or it may have been configured not to send TTL Exceeded (or any ICMP) messages in response.  so most of this happens below the level where syns and acks come into the picture. have you checked canyouseeme.org?

@FrankThomas the canyouseeme gives a connectiontimedout message

@tuskiomi - I am a doofus. I read one thing and typed another. I meant to ask, before it stopped working, I presume tracerout was working? I presume you have checked your modem’s IP address, and verified, the address hasn’t changed? Since your being assigned a public address your modem should be used not a website.

traceroute was working before, correct. The address has not changed no.

@Ramhound see above ^

I’ve had this issue before. Do you have a firewall? I’d Use an external service like CanYouSeeMe.org or YouGetSignal’s Port Checker to see if the necessary ports are open and reachable from outside your network.

@security_paranoid i did use canyouseeme, it gets a timeout. I am using a firewall, but not at the router level. All internal LAN connections are able to be made.
